# Eclipse Java Mars unable to launch?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to launch following hello world program why?
Heres the code `package FistjavaTing;`

```
public class FistClass {
public void main(){
    System.out.print("Hello Word");
}}
```

I get this error 
[image]

Comment: It's not "ok" to just post an image and a question. Put your code in the question.

Comment: `static` is required on a `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
package FirstjavaTing;

public class FistClass {

   public static void main(){
        System.out.print("Hello Word");
    }
}
```